# When uninstalling SSL letsencrypt by commenting out, will stop httpd?

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have SSL setup on 2 domains. I didn't do it, another team member did. The first domain, domain1.com and the second domain, domain2.com.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem
```

The reason I'm disabling this is because PayPal IPNs are not coming in on domain2.com. That's another story though.

I commented out those 2 lines, but then httpd won't start. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: When _“httpd won't start”_, first thing you do is go check the error log.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve here? Do you want this Virtualhost(?) to use a different certificate? Or do you not want it to be reachable via HTTPS/port 443 any more at all? (In that case, remove the VHost.)

Comment: If you have SSL enabled you have to provide a certificate and a key file.